# PHP - Does it replace the index?

Tags: php, web

PHP is a mystery for me. In the FTP main directory of my website, I uploaded 2 files: a.txt and b.txt. If I enter my website address in my browser I can view both a.txt and b.txt. However when I upload a file named index.php or default.php, I can only see a blank page when I refresh my browser.

My question: how does it work and is it enough to keep my files unaccessible?

Answer (score 3):

It's not really a PHP thing.

Practically since the *beginning*, web servers have had a concept of the "index page" or "default page", almost always named `index.html`. If there's an "index" file in a directory, it is shown; otherwise, a list of files is shown. (It's even got a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webserver_directory_index).)

The usual index file names are `index.html` or `index.htm`, sometimes also `default.html` (`.htm`). When the server has PHP installed, it just adds one more name, `index.php`, to that list.

Comment: Is it enough to keep my other files unaccessible?

Comment: `Is it enough to keep my other files unaccessible?` - **No.** It is absolutely **not a security measurment**. Global security settings of your web server or security settings for this particular directory will define what is accessible and for whom.